# MongoDB - grouping and sorting by linked lists

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB 3.4.23, I have a "threaded" data structure in which the documents represent comments. If there's more than one comment in a thread, they're connected in a simple linked list. The "reply_to" field is null for the first comment in a thread (or for unthreaded single comments), and then each reply_to contains the id of the previous comment in the thread. A simplified example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e169c12ede98842e97f8a82"),
    "id" : "1215111156496576513",
    "text" : "Comment 1",
    "reply_to" : null
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e169c98a3c7e254f2767d03"),
    "id" : "1215111718625533952",
    "text" : "Comment 2",
    "reply_to" : "1215111156496576513"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e169d46e62cc449d874d532"),
    "id" : "1215112448862277634",
    "text" : "Comment 3",
    "reply_to" : "1215111718625533952"
}
```

A thread like this may not have consecutive IDs, and is surrounded by lots of other comments, some in threads, some not. What I'd like to do is write an aggregation pipeline that could show all the documents grouped and sorted by these threads, but I'm relatively new to MongoDB and this one has me stumped. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/).

### Explanation:

It performs a recursive search on a collection. For each `id` it connects documents by `reply_to` field.
`depth` field indicates what hierarchy level is current message.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "reply_to": null
    }
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$id",
      connectFromField: "id",
      connectToField: "reply_to",
      as: "thread",
      depthField: "depth"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$thread"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "thread.depth": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      thread: {
        $push: "$thread"
      },
      root: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      id: "$root.id",
      text: "$root.text",
      reply_to: "$root.reply_to",
      thread: "$thread"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9xsgD75in_E)

---

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e169c12ede98842e97f8a82"),
    "id": "1215111156496576513",
    "reply_to": null,
    "text": "Comment 1",
    "thread": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e169c98a3c7e254f2767d03"),
        "depth": 0,
        "id": "1215111718625533952",
        "reply_to": "1215111156496576513",
        "text": "Comment 2"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e169d46e62cc449d874d532"),
        "depth": 1,
        "id": "1215112448862277634",
        "reply_to": "1215111718625533952",
        "text": "Comment 3"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5e169d46e62cc449d874d534"),
        "depth": 2,
        "id": "1215112448862277639",
        "reply_to": "1215112448862277634",
        "text": "Comment 4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#considerations

Does it fit your expectation?

Comment: Thank you! That looks awesome, but unfortunately the $mergeObjects operator isn't supported in version 3.4. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: Yes. Use `$project` instead of `$replaceRoot` like this: `{$project:{id:"$root.id", text:"$root.text", thread:"$thread", so on }}`

Comment: It runs at Mongo Playground, but I replaced the `$replaceRoot` and `$project` sections with this: `{ $project: { id: "$root.id", text: "$root.text", thread: "$thread" } }` and now I'm getting another error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'`

Comment: This is the complete error message in the shell: `E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' @(shell):1:0`

Comment: Can you post query you are running in the shell?

Comment: Got it! I had forgotten to replace "collection" in the graphLookup section with the actual name of the collection. It works now, thank you very much. It does take quite a while to work through a collection of about 5000 docs.

Comment: One more question - is it possible to also sort the results by the root comment's id field?

Comment: Nice . Sure, you can add as last stage a sort operator